# Amplitude of the electric field due to Fraunhofer's diffraction through a slit

Tags: optics, diffraction

In Hetch's *Optics* book, the irradiance $I$ due to Fraunhofer's diffraction in the case of a slit of height $l$ in the $y$ axis and width $b$ in the $z$ axis is given by

$$I(\theta)=I(0)\left(\frac{\sin \beta}{\beta}\right)^{2}, \text{ with } \beta=(kb / 2) \sin \theta$$

[image]

However, it doesn't say anything about the amplitude of the field $E$. What would be the expression of the amplitude of the field $E$ in this case? May it perhaps be derived from the expression of the amplitude in the case of a rectangular aperture,

$$\tilde{E}=\frac{A \mathcal{E}_{A} e^{i(\omega t-k R)}}{R}\left(\frac{\sin \alpha^{\prime}}{\alpha^{\prime}}\right)\left(\frac{\sin \beta^{\prime}}{\beta^{\prime}}\right)$$

with $\beta' =k b Y / 2 R $ and $\alpha'=k a Z / 2 R$?

Answer (score 0):

The irradiance  is given by $I = \frac{1}{2\eta} |E|^2$, where $\eta$ is the characteristic impedance of the medium, and $E$ is the electrical field strength. For vacuum we have $\eta = 377\Omega$

Answer (score 0):

The simple formula from Hetch assumes that the intensity of the disturbance at a point on a line parallel to z and at an R much greater the the width of the slit is proportional to the maximum E squared, and that the height of the slit is large compared to the width.  This means the term with B' approaches one (Y = 0), the oscillating exponential is set to one, and the square of the constants are replaced by I(0).  Note that your a' corresponds with his B.